# Hide MS Office add-in from programs and feature after installation using c#

Tags: c#, registry, add-in

I don't want to show my powerpoint addin from programs and feature in control panel after installation.

For this I tried to add **systemcomponent** property in registry **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall** after adding this manually **Add-in** was successfully hide from programs and features but when I tried to do this from my code, getting an exception of type **ThrowUnauthorizedAccessException** (exception error message "**Cannot write to the registry key**") althought I am running that **.exe** on Admin mode. I am not figuring it out how to add this property in "**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**" directory using C# code.

If this is not the right solution to do this so what else I can do?

Here is my code

```
RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", true);

        foreach (var subkey in registry.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey productKey = registry.OpenSubKey(subkey);
            if (productKey != null)
            {
                foreach (var value in productKey.GetValueNames())
                {
                    string keyValue = Convert.ToString(productKey.GetValue(value));

                    if (keyValue.ToLower().Contains("myaddin"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            productKey.SetValue("SystemComponent", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                            productKey.Close();
                            return;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @CherryDT now you can check.